# I can't solve error CS7036 in unity: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got this error in the unity console, but I can't find the problem. I think everthing is correct? I just write it down from a curs in udemy, he uses visual studio, and i use vsc, i dont think that is a problem. but its clearly the same, how it looks in the tutorial.thanks for help.

*1/2 properties.cs:*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Properties : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        /* EIGENSCHAFTEN (C# Properties) */

        Student Jordan = new Student("Jordan", "Smith", 31);

        Debug.Log(Jordan.FirstName);
        Debug.Log(Jordan.LastName);
        Debug.Log(Jordan.FullName);
        Debug.Log(Jordan.Age);




    }
}
```

*2/2 student.cs*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Student
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; } }

    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public Student(string firstName, string lastName, string fullName, int age)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Age = age;
    }

}
```

> error in unity -> error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'age' of 'Student.Student(string, string, string, int)'

Comment: You're missing a parameter in ` Student("Jordan", "Smith", 31);` the constructor has 4 parameters not 3

Comment: It's unclear why you wanted callers to pass `fullName` when you just calculate it, so maybe you intended to remove that parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only passed 3 parameters to your constructor but you defined it with 4

Since you have custom getter for FullName i guess best solution for you would be to remove it from constructo

```
public Student(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
{
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    Age = age;
}
```

Alternative would be just to overload contstructor and write another combination for it